# Embeddable generating wrong field index

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I got a table that contains (amongst others), columns

```
docusign_account_id TEXT NOT NULL,
docusign_envelope_id TEXT NOT NULL,
```

(which are the only `docusign_...` columns).

I'd like to bundle those into an embeddable with a configuration like

```
embeddables {
    embeddable {
        name = "DOCUSIGN_ENVELOPE_DETAILS"
        tables = "version"
        fields {
            field {
                name = "ENVELOPE_ID"
                expression = "DOCUSIGN_ENVELOPE_ID"
            }
            field {
                name = "ACCOUNT_ID"
                expression = "DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

turns out, though, that I'm running into nullpointer exceptions actually using those because the setter for the embeddable does not use the correct indices for the fields,
e.g. offset `15` for the field, but offset `16` when set by embeddable

```
/**
 * Setter for <code>public.version.docusign_account_id</code>.
 */
public void setDocusignAccountId(String value) {
    set(15, value);
}
```

```
/**
 * Setter for the embeddable <code>public.DOCUSIGN_ENVELOPE_DETAILS</code>.
 */
public void setDocusignEnvelopeDetails(DocusignEnvelopeDetailsRecord value) {
    set(12, value.getEnvelopeId());
    set(16, value.getAccountId());
}
```

Not sure how to resolve this (other than just avoiding the "feature" altogether).

Manual correction will un-correct this on next codegen.

Is there additional configuration that needs be done?

Comment: That looks like a bug. Would you mind reporting it with a few more reproduction steps here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose (mostly, including the `CREATE TABLE` statement, plus any other code generation configuration that you've used)